# How to align text to the right and turn to the left on same time?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to align a text to the right completely but at the same time that the text is to the left. For example:

[image]

```css
.u-right-horizontal {
  text-align: right;
  text-align-last: left;
  text-justify: left;
}
```

```html
<div>HTML here please!</div>
```

But I have only been able to align them to the right And what I have is:

[image]

Here my CSS property:

```
.u-right-horizontal {
  text-align: right;
  text-align-last: left;
  text-justify: left;
}
```

I would like to have the text as in the first attached photo. But I've only gotten as far as the second attached photo with the css property.

If you could help me I would be grateful!

Comment: Please update with functional HTML and CSS.  I added a snippet to get you started.  Without HTML we are only guessing here.

Comment: What defines the width of that part with the text in it?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. They had already answered my question, however, thank you very much for editing my code and giving me an effective tool (I would gladly give you the green check, for the tool but as another user answered my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to push only the wrapped container div to the right. For that you can use for example `margin-left: auto;`.

**working example**

```css
.w {
  background: gray;
  
}
.sum {
  background: green;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="sum">
    <p>lorem: 123</p>
    <p>lorem: 456</p>
    <p>lorem: 678</p>
    <p>sum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's what I was looking for. Thank you very much: D

Comment: @SamuelD. You welcome Samuel! :-)